# Fibonacci in Go using channels

Tags: go, fibonacci

I am following the examples on tour.golang.org.

I understand the example mostly, the only issue I have is why does it stop when we pass 0 to quit channel? Regardless of whether 0 was passed to quit,  there is always a value for x. So shouldn't select always fall on case 'c <- x' ?

```
func fibonacci(c chan int, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            return
        }
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Comment: What I didn't understand even more is how the `close(c)` is ever going to get executed. But it appears that in the [current version](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) the close has disappeared, along with the type of parameter c. I would instead have clarified the types as `fibonacci(c chan<- int, quit <-chan int)` but I am a go-noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is always a value for x. So shouldn't select always fall on case 'c <- x' ?

No, because this channel is unbuffered, the send will block until someone can receive from it.

Read about channels on [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels):

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive. **If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.** If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks only until the value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is full, this means waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

Additionally, if 2 cases in a select statement could proceed, [one is picked pseudo-randomly](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements).

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one of the communications can proceed.